# How to added database value?

Tags: android

I have to insert in SqLlite one column total.Many more value is insert i want all value added?

For example Column name Total insert value 23.0,45.0,56.0  i want insert all number added.

Comment: Huh?? Please explain a little bit more.

Comment: What is your problem..? it is basic addition..If anything else Explain your question clearly

Comment: I have used in custom listview used it base adapter.But this total value we can show it listview so how to get holder value in added?

Comment: I suppose he has a table with columns like `[Number], [Total]` and wants to do like this `insert (23, 134); insert (45, 134); insert (56, 134)`. Though it is very strange table design and such column is completely useless because you can calculate sum in a select query (like `select sum([Number]) from [Table]`).

Answer (score 2):

You can just sum the values in the SQL statement:

```
insert into tableName (total, ....) values (23.0 + 45.0 + 56.0, ...)
```

As simple as that.